# TableCellRenderer repeating after 4238 rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm working on a large JTable (over 4500 row and 17 columns). Everything works fine until I reached the 4238th row. At that point, the renderer is repeated until the end of the JTable even if I filter it.

My data is stored into an ArrayList of object and the model extends an AbstractTableModel.

Is anybody encounter this issue previously or had an idea of what the issue could be? I have been completely unsuccessful in finding any threads related to this problem.

Comment: the probability that the bug is in your code rather than in the JDK is quite high, so you should show your code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `My data is stored into an ArrayList of object and the model extends an AbstractTableModel.` - so what happens when you use the DefaultTableModel, instead of your custom model. Also, make sure your testing is done with default renderers to see if it works. I would guess the problem is in your custom model or renderer.

Comment: Good thought camickr. I will try to use the DefaultTableModel to make sure my TableModel is not causing the issue. I am actually building simple version of my code (I will edit my question).

Comment: @Pat by default is painted only visible Rectangle from JTable, then there doesn't matter if is there matrix 5k x 20, can be important for preformace by using RowSorter/Filter

Comment: The issue came from my data. One of my table have been wrongly updated. Thanks for your answers.